# Generar un diagrama E-R en IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: orm, intellij-idea, diagrama-er

Quisiera generar un erd en IDEA. He visto que [es posible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187048/tool-to-generate-a-erd-entity-relation-diagram-based-on-jpa-annotations) si tienes un `persistence.xml` que en mi caso no tengo.

¿Existe alguna forma de generalo puramente como ERD o debo conformarme con el diagrama de clases UML que genera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras verificar la pestaña de persistencia en mi IDEA Ultimate ví que es posible ya que detecta el mapeo mediante las anotaciones `@Entity`.

[image: opción para generar diagrama ER en IDEA]

Se ve un poco diferente a como cuando tiene la persistencia definida en un archivo, pero la generación no encesita nada extra.